# Showing why a form is not exact

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Consider the differential form

$$\omega=\frac{y dx-x dy}{x^2+y^2}$$ on $\mathbb{R}^2-0$.
I have proved the following.

1-This $1$-form is closed on $\mathbb{R}^2-0$.

2-If $f_n:S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2-0$ is the map $$f_n(\theta)=(\cos(n \theta), \sin(n \theta))$$
Then
$$\int_{S^1} f_n^* \omega= 2\pi n \neq 0$$

and this is where I am stuck.

3-Use the previous parts to show that the form $\omega$ is not exact.

> My Thoughts-
> If $\omega=d\tau$ is exact, then $d \omega =d^2 \tau=0$ and thus $f_n^* d \omega = d(f_n^* \omega)=0$ . But now I am not sure what to do next? I am thinking about using stokes theorem and looking for guidance in that direction.

Comment: Part 2 doesn't remind you of a theorem that you have encountered before regarding exact forms? The way I read your exercise statement, it was clearly meant to.

Comment: @Arthur, Do you mean I can use that every exact form integrates to 0 over a manifold without boundary.  Here $S^1$ is a manifold without boundary so we can immediately conclude that?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: and this is what I am confused about.  it shows that the form $f_n^*\omega$ is not exact in $S^1$ but what about $\omega $ on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: If the equation $\omega = d\phi$ holds on $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$, then isn't $f_n^*\omega = d(f_n^*\phi)$ exact?  Also, note that $f_1^*\omega$ is just the restriction of $\omega$ to $S^1\subset\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$.

Answer (score 4):

The comments give a clear explanation, which I'll re-present here.

Suppose for contradiction that $\omega$ is exact. Then $\omega = d\eta$ for some $0$-form $\eta$. Now
$$f_1^* \omega = f_1^*(d \eta) = d (f_1^* \eta),$$
so by Stokes' Theorem
$$2\pi = \int_{S^1} f_1^* \omega = \int_{S^1} d(f_1^* \eta) = \int_{\partial S^1} f_1^* \eta.$$
On the other hand, since $\partial S^1 = \varnothing$, this integral equals $0$. Contradiction!

Comment: @draacdeltafunk, you said you used stokes theorem. but I cannot figure out how  What is your manifold?  What is your boundary?

Comment: @permutation_matrix Stokes' theorem is in the final equality. They left out the intermediate $\int_{\partial S^1} f_1^*\eta$

Comment: The intermediate step seems to be the most important thing to point out to the OP though.

Comment: I've now edited the answer to spell out this step.

Answer (score 3):

For
$$\tag{1}
\omega=\frac{y\,dx-x\,dy}{x^2+y^2}=a\,dx+b\,dy
$$
we have
\begin{align}
d\omega&=(\partial_ya)\,dx\wedge dy+(\partial_xb)\,dy\wedge dx\\
&=\frac{(x^2-y^2)\,dx\wedge dy+(x^2-y^2)\,dy\wedge dx}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=0\tag{2}
\end{align}
because $dx\wedge dy$ is antisymmetric.

- $\omega$ is defined only on the punctured, and therefore non-simply connected, domain $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\,.$ The  [Poincare lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar%C3%A9_lemma) says that, in general, only on simply connected domains all closed $p$-forms, with $p=1\,,$ are exact. (For $p>1$, thanks to a comment by peek-a-boo
  one works with star-shaped domains in that case or assumes that the domain is [contractible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space).)
- Because the vector field of which $\omega$ is the dual, namely,
  $$\tag{3}
  \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\begin{pmatrix}y\\-x\end{pmatrix}\,,
  $$
  is tangent to the circles around the origin it looks geometrically as if it should have rotation. But since $\omega$ is closed it doesn't! We have here an example of an [irrotational vortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity#Examples).
- The form (1) occurs as a local gauge transformation in the Wu-Yang
  monopole which was in 1975 the first solution of the Yang-Mills field
  equations [1]. This $\omega$ is also well-known as the generator of the first
  [de-Rham cohomology group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms) of the punctured plane $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\,.$
- Let's look for the function $\phi$ on any simply connected domain $D\subset\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ that satisfies
  $$\tag{4}
  \omega=d\phi\,.
  $$
  It turns out that this function is given in polar coordinates by
  $$\tag{5}
  \phi(r,\theta)=-\theta\,.
  $$
  The graph of this function is a helix.
  In Cartesian coordinates this is
  $$\tag{6}
  \phi(x,y)=-{\rm sign}( y)\,\arccos\Big(\textstyle\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\Big)\,
  $$
  but we will not use that.
  Since,
  \begin{align}\tag{7}
  \begin{pmatrix}\partial_x\\\partial_y \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\partial_r\\\frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta\end{pmatrix}
  \end{align}
  it is easy to see from $\partial_r\phi=0$ and $\partial_\theta\phi=-1$ that
  \begin{align}\tag{8}
  \partial_x\phi=\frac{r\sin\theta}{r^2}=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\,,\quad\partial_y\phi=\frac{-r\cos\theta}{r^2}=\frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}
  \end{align}
  which shows
  $$\tag{9}
  d\phi=(\partial_x\phi)\,dx+(\partial_y\phi)\,dy=\omega\,.
  $$
- The maximal domain on which this $\phi$ can be defined without becoming multivalued is $\mathbb R^2$ with a branch cut, say, $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{x\ge 0,y=0\}\,,$ similar to the complex logarithm.

[image]

- The example (1) is very popular in homework exercises. I am a bit surprised that the following closed form which is not exact is rarely seen: Instead of (4) and (5) one could take an arbitrary strictly decreasing function $f:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb R$ and define
  $$\tag{10}
  \omega=d\phi=df(\theta)\,.
  $$
  Clearly, $\omega$ is closed, $d\omega=dd\phi=0$ but its integral
  around the circle $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ is $f(2\pi)-f(0)<0\,.$ For example
  when $f(\theta)=-\frac{1}{2}\theta^2$ then $\partial_r\phi=0$ and $\partial_\theta\phi=-\theta$ so that here, instead of (8), and using (6),
  \begin{align}\tag{11}
  \partial_x\phi&=\theta\frac{r\sin\theta}{r^2}={\rm sign}( y)\,
  \arccos\Big(\textstyle\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\Big)\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,,\\[2mm]
  \partial_y\phi&=-\theta\frac{r\cos\theta}{r^2}={\rm sign}( y)\,
  \arccos\Big(\textstyle\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\Big)\frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,.\tag{12}
  \end{align}
  This leads to
  $$\tag{13}
  \omega={\rm sign}( y)\,\arccos\Big(\textstyle\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\Big)\displaystyle\frac{y\,dx-x\,dy}{x^2+y^2}\,.
  $$
  But that form is not continuous on $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ for the same
  reason that the function $\phi$ from (5) and (6) was not continuous.
- In this [related  post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720233/examples-of-conservative-vector-fields-in-the-plane-whose-closed-line-integral-i/4720554#4720554) it is further explained that there are essentially no other one-forms sharing the properties of $\omega$ from (1).

[1] M. Nakahara, *Geometry, Topology and Physics*

Comment: Your equation (6) is correct only on the portion of $D$ with $y\ge 0$. So (13) fails to be valid.

Comment: @TedShifrin (6) and (13) should be correct now.

Comment: No. Now you have an obviously discontinuous function.

Comment: @TedShifrin True. The map $(x,y)\mapsto\theta$ can't be made continuous. You finally convinced me that the original $\omega$ from (1) has a reason to be so ubiquitous.

Comment: Actually, it can be made continuous on a simply connected domain in the punctured plane, but certainly not on the whole punctured plane. This is the whole point. But you can pull back $d\theta$ by any diffeomorphism …

Comment: @TedShifrin . Yes, as far as its domain and continuity is concerned this  $\omega$  in (13) is obviously just a sister of the function I plotted in 3d. The beauty of $\omega$ in (1) is that its properties are not that obvious at first glance in cartesian coordinates. If there are similar $\omega$ I'd be glad to solve those exercises.

Comment: “*The Poincare lemma says that, in general, only on simply connected domains all closed $p$-forms, with $p\geq 1$, are exact.*” Unfortunately this is not true, (it is for $p=1$ though). For $p>1$, simply-connected is no longer sufficient. That’s why Poincare’s lemma is usually stated with the simple sufficient condition of “star-shaped”.

Comment: @peek-a-boo . Thanks! I did an update. The Wikipedia article that made this claim has [citation needed].

Comment: btw, it’s not that one “needs” star-shaped, as in “needs” seems to imply that we’re talking about necessary conditions, when we’re actually talking about sufficient conditions. Also, the Wikipedia article refers to open balls and contractible spaces (unless it was just recently edited) which is fine for Poincare’s lemma. Also, if we’re only interested in specific values of $p$, we can weaken the contractibility assumption accordingly.

Comment: @peek-a-boo . That was clear but I better removed the "needs". Let me know again if there is a better wording and thanks for reading so carefully. It is the MSE users like you from whom I learned the most in the past two years.

Comment: @peek-a-boo In fact, I think I get it now: Wikipedia seems ok about Poincare lemma, as contractible is stronger than simply connected, at least according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space) again.