# How to compute the exterior derivative of $\omega := \frac{x^1dx^2 - x^2dx^1}{(x^1)^2+(x^2)^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

> Let $dx^I$ be local coordinates and let $$\omega := \frac{x^1dx^2 - x^2dx^1}{(x^1)^2+(x^2)^2}.$$
> Compute $d\omega$ for $(x^1,x^2) \ne 0$.
>
> **Remark:** $d\omega$ means the exterior derivative, which we defined in the lecture as
>
> $$d(f \ dx^I) = df \wedge dx^I$$
>
> , where $df$ is the differential of $f$.

I can see that transfering $(x^1,x^2)$ into polar coordinates $y^I:=(r, \alpha)$ it holds $d\alpha = \omega$, so we are left to compute $d\omega = dd\alpha$. However, I do not see how to evaluate $d\alpha$.

If I am not mistaken $\alpha$ should be a $1$-form, so

$$d(\alpha \ dy^I) = d\alpha \wedge dy^I = 1 \wedge dr \wedge d\alpha,$$

but I am not sure what to do now. Could you please give me hint?

Comment: You may also want to study my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4605719/949989) which is discussing the question to what extend this form is / is not ***exact***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall write $x=x^1$ and $y=x^2\,.$ Your one-form is
$$\tag{1}
\omega=f\,dx+g\,dy\,,\quad f(x,y):=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\,,\quad g(x,y):=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\,.
$$
and, in Cartesian coordinates,
\begin{align}
d\omega&=\partial_yf\,dy\wedge dx+\partial_xg\,dx\wedge dy\\[2mm]
&=\frac{(y^2-x^2)\,dy\wedge dx+(y^2-x^2)\,dx\wedge dy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\\
&=0\,.\tag{2}
\end{align}
In polar coordinates,
\begin{align}\tag{3}
dx&=\cos\alpha\,dr-r\sin\alpha\,d\alpha\,,\quad &dy&=\sin\alpha\,dr+r\cos\alpha\,d\alpha\,,\\[2mm]
dr&=\cos\alpha\,dx+\sin\alpha\,dy\,,\quad
&r\,d\alpha&=-\sin\alpha\,dx+\cos\alpha\,dy\,.\tag{4}
\end{align}
so that ***indeed***, from the expression for $r\,d\alpha$ in (4),

\begin{align}
\omega=d\alpha\,.
\end{align}
This leads to
\begin{align}
d\omega=0
\end{align}
as it should.

Another way to see that $\omega=d\alpha$ is to differentiate
$$
\alpha=\arccos\Big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\Big)
$$
w.r.t. $x$ and $y\,.$

Comment: @3nondatur I don't understand what that $\omega\,dx^I$ is when $\omega=f\,dx+g\,dy$. When you apply the [differentiation rule of a $k$-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#In_terms_of_local_coordinates) $\varphi$ to the one-form $\omega$ you get what I wrote.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still do not get it. When I use the definition from my lecture I only get $d(\omega \ dx^I) = d\omega \wedge dx^I = d(f \ dx + g \ dy) \wedge dx^I = d(f \ dx)\wedge dx^I + d(g \  dy) \wedge dx^I $, but I do not see how to compute the differentials $d(f \ dx)$ and $d(g \  dy)$ now.

Comment: By your own definition in OP, $\omega$ is of the form $f\,dx^1+g\,dx^2\,.$ What do you want with $dx^I\,?$ You can omit it. The Wikipedia link I provided shows that $d\omega=d(f\,dx^1+g\,dx^2)=(\partial_2 f)\,dx^2\wedge dx^1+(\partial_1 g)\,dx^1\wedge dx^2\,.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I understand it now (I got confused with the notation).