# Are $\phi$ and $\hat z$ 'dual' in $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: 3d, differential-forms, spherical-coordinates, exterior-derivative

Consider $\mathbb R^3$ and the following equation
\begin{equation}
\star d\omega=df
\end{equation}
where $f$ is a 0-form and $\omega$ is a 1-form. My question is whether this equation is satisfied by
\begin{align}
\omega&=\hat z \delta(x)\delta(y) \\
f&=\phi
\end{align}
where $(x,y,z)$ are the Cartesian coordinates, $\hat z$ is the unit vector in the $z$ direction, $(r,\theta,\phi)$ are the spherical polar coordinates and $\delta(\cdot)$ is the Dirac delta function. I find this difficult to compute because of the delta functions.

Edit: It turns out that this is false. The formula I was looking for is actually $\epsilon_{ijk}[\partial_{j},\partial_{k}]\phi=\hat z_i \delta(x)\delta(y)$.

Comment: You told us what $z$ is. What is $\hat{z}$?

Comment: @KurtG. It's the unit vector in the $z$ direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Part I.***

I am assuming that the polar coordinates are related to the Cartesian coordinates
by
$$
x=r\sin\theta\cos\phi\,,\quad y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi\,,\quad z=r\cos\theta
$$
so that
$$
f(r,\theta,\phi)=\phi=\arccos\Big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\Big)\,.
$$
From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4615003/949989) we know that
$$
df=d\phi=\frac{x\,dy-y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}\,.
$$
The [Hodge dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Three_dimensions) of this is
$$
\star df=\frac{x\,dz\wedge dx-y\,dy\wedge dz}{x^2+y^2}\,.
$$
The right hand side of this is $d\omega$ which can be written as
$$
d\omega=dz\wedge\frac{x\,dx+y\,dy}{x^2+y^2}\,.
$$
This shows that
$$
\omega=-\frac{\log(x^2+y^2)}{2}\,dz\,.
$$
The function $-\frac{\log(x^2+y^2)}{2}$ is not the product of two delta functions $\delta(x)\delta(y)$ but it has a pole at the origin and its integral over the unit disc is
$$
-\pi\int_0^1\log (r^2)\,r\,dr=-2\pi\int_0^1(\log r)\,r\,dr
=2\pi\int_0^1 \frac{r^2}{2r}\,dr-2\pi(\log r)r^2\Big|_0^1=\frac{\pi}{2}\,.
$$

***Part II.***

You want to know if
$$\tag{1}
\epsilon_{ijk}\,[\partial_{j},\partial_{k}]\,\phi=\hat z_i\,\delta(x)\delta(y)
$$
is true. The left hand side of this contains the gradient of $\phi$ which we know from above is
$$
\nabla\phi=\partial_k\,\phi=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\begin{pmatrix}-y\\x\\0 \end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Since $\epsilon_{ijk}\,a_j\,b_k=(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})_i$ we have
$$
\epsilon_{ijk}\,\partial_j\,\partial_k\,\phi=(\nabla\times(\nabla\phi))_i
$$
which is zero for all $x,y\not=0\,.$ Therefore,
$$
\epsilon_{ijk}\,[\partial_j,\partial_k]\,\phi=0\,\quad\text{ for all }x,y\not=0\,.
$$
Let $S^1$ be the unit circle around the origin in the $xy$-plane. Since
$$
\int_{S^1}d\phi=\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\phi=2\pi
$$
there seems a contradiction to the Stokes theorem because from $dd\phi=0$ it should follow that this integral must be zero. The problem is however
that $\phi$ is undefined in the origin and the Stokes theorem can be
"preserved" when in the distributional sense the rotation of $d\phi$ is
given by those delta functions in (1).