# Find $ \oint_c \frac{-y}{x^2+4y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2+4y^2}dy$ when $c$ is the unit circle.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

Find $$  \oint_c  \frac{-y}{x^2+4y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2+4y^2}dy$$ when $c$ is the unit circle (Counterclockwise).

My attempt:

Denote $P=\frac{-y}{x^2+4y^2}, Q=\frac{x}{x^2+4y^2}$.

$Q_x=\frac{4y^2-x^2}{(x^2+4y^2)^2}, P_y=\frac{4y^2-x^2}{(x^2+4y^2)^2}$

Using Green's Theorem $  \oint_c  \frac{-y}{x^2+4y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2+4y^2}dy = \int\int_c Q_x-P_y=\int\int_c 0=0$

I am not entirely sure that I can use Green's Theorem , is my solution correct ?

Comment: No, Green's theorem doesn't apply. Check the conditions again

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4605719/949989). A very popular exercise it seems. To replace $y^2$ by $4y^2$ shows a lack of creativity on the side of those inventing such homework tasks.

Comment: @KurtG How do you propose to be creative? Translate the origin instead? ‍♂️‍♂️ Do you want to pull back by a crazy diffeomorphism mapping the origin to the origin?

Comment: @TedShifrin . Sorry for that provocative comment. I have updated the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4605719/949989) to explain what I mean. Thanks much for taking an interest. Your comments are always welcome. Feel free to critisise it also.