# Counterexamples to "irrotational implies potential"

Tags: vector-analysis, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

I'm trying to figure out some counterexamples of the following: If $F$ is an irrotational vector field then there exists some $U$ such that $F = \text{grad}(U)$ (or more generally, using the language of forms, I'm trying to find a closed form which is not exact).

As @peek-a-boo suggested I Googled a bit and found out the following example. In $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ the vector field
$$F(x,y) := \left( -\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2},\ \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} \right)$$
is closed (it has zero rotational) but not exact (it is not the gradient of any other function).

I would really appreciate if

- Someone could give me more examples of such vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$.
- More generally, someone could provide me with some examples of $k$-forms $\omega$ on n-dimensional manifolds $M$ such that its de Rham cohomology class $[\omega]$ is nonzero.

**EDITED:** I corrected the observations made in the first four comments, and also @Ted Shifrin's comment.

Comment: Did you search the site? Or google? There are several posts about closed non-exact forms. Btw you have a typo: there is no such thing as an exact form which is not closed.

Comment: the divergence take a vector field as entry and gives a function, so "$F = \operatorname{div} U$ for $F$ a vector field is nonsense. Did you mean the gradient of a function?

Comment: If you're only looking at subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then you're limited to punching holes and creating vector fields that wind around them. That's not much "harder" than a single hole. What the vector field dual to $d\theta$ on the cylinder $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$? or on the torus $S^1 \times S^1$?

Comment: What a mess. As Didier already said, a vector field cannot be the divergence of a vector field, as the latter is a scalar function. And every $C^1$ exact form is automatically closed (because $d^2=0$), no matter the domain. Please rethink your question. Do you want to be thinking about a vector field that is not $C^1$ on a domain rather than a domain with some sort of hole?

Comment: I apologize for this mess. I should've Googled a bit more, and I also got confused with names (rotational, divergence, exact, closed...). I believe now the question makes more sense. Thanks for all your corrections.

Comment: At the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605443/showing-why-a-form-is-not-exact/4605719#4605719) I made a few attempts to come up with other examples which do not just pull back that ubiquitous $\omega$ in OP. As you can see it was not successful.

Comment: Because the cohomology of $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$ comes from the circle sitting in there, up to diffeomorphic changes of coordinates, there are no other examples. For your final question, you say $n$-form on a manifold. Why specify $n$? Is the manifold $n$-dimensional? If so, there is a non-exact $n$-form if and only if the manifold is compact and orientable.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for this additional example! I guess this non-exact n-form is the volume form, am I right? When I wrote n-form, I meant an arbitrary form, n not necessarily being the dimension of the manifold. I'll edit this now.