# Vector field is conservative: proof verification

Tags: solution-verification, vector-analysis, vector-fields, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I've been trying to prove that this vector field:
$$
\vec{F}=\left(\frac{y}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}+y^{2}},\frac{1-x}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}+y^{2}}\right)
$$
Is conservative in:
$$
D=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\mid1\leq\left(x+1\right)^{2}+y^{2}\leq2\right\} 
$$
**Proof attempt #1:**
To my understanding, it holds that in a *simply-connected domain*, a vector field $P\hat{x}+Q\hat{y}$ whose partial derivatives are continuous is conservative if and only if $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$.
I confirmed that in the circle centered at $\left(-1,0\right)$ with a radius of $2$, which is a superset of $D$, the partial derivatives are indeed continuous, and furthermore that:
$$
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\left(x-1\right)^{2}-y^{2}}{\left(\left(x-1\right)^{2}+y^{2}\right)^{2}} =  \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}
$$
So in that circle, $\vec{F}$ is indeed conservative.
Thus: for any closed, piecewise-smooth curve in that circle, we have that the line integral of $\vec{F}$ over that curve is $0$. Since any such curve in $D$ is also a curve in the circle (and since adding that hole-of-radius-1 in the middle of it doesn't affect any of the components of a line integral: the field in all points on the curve and any parametrization of the curve, then it also doesn't affect the line integral itself), we have that every such curve *in D* also has that property, and so $\vec{F}$ is conservative there, as well.

Does the above proof seem okay (if I make it a tad more rigorous, maybe)?

**Proof attempt #2:**
Another possible proof method that I'd considered might be using Green's Theorem to show that the line integral over the unit circle centered at $\left(-1,0\right)$ results in $0$, and then use a theorem (which I believe I can prove) by which if a field has the aforementioned property of $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ (and probably a few other requirements) then any closed, simple curve around such a "hole" in its domain would result in the exact same value, so not exactly conservative because that value doesn't have to be $0$, but since I already showed that one such integral does evaluate to $0$, then all of them do, so the field is indeed conservative.
Does this one make sense?

Comment: Both of those seem fine. I see the problem is being cute by using a field with a delta function curl at $(1,0)$, but said delta function is on the outside of $D$.

Comment: Thanks, @eyeballfrog – iirc, before trying to show that it is conservative in this $D$, I showed that it *isn't* conservative in a similar circle, centered at the problematic point ($(1,0)$) – I did this by computing a line integral over a circle around the center and showing it is nonzero. I'm not sure what curl/delta function are yet, but I assume this is related?

Comment: Yeah, the vector field has zero curl at all points except $(1,0)$, where it's undefined. However, the integral around any curve that contains $(1,0)$ will have the same constant value. So it's as though the field has nonzero total curl, but it's all "concentrated" at $(1,0)$.  A delta function refers to this phenomenon, where all of the value of a function seems to be concentrated at a single point. It's a kind of handwavey thing, because no actual function can have this property, but it turns out there is a way to put it on solid ground with more complicated math.

Comment: The vector field is yet another tweak of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4605719/949989). We can safely say that it is conservative in any domain that does not allow closed curves around the singularity. (Your $D$ fulfils that condition.) A look at the picture in the link should make visually clear on what domains the field is conservative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, guys – very helpful and interesting :) Looking forward to learning more about this.