# Proof for component test for conservative fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The test for conservative fields is as follows:

The 2D vetor field is conservative if and only if:

$$∂_xF_y=∂_yF_x$$

$$∂_yF_x=∂_xF_y$$

The forward proof is quite straight forward to me, but I got stuck proving backwards.

I have tried using Green's Theorem:

from $∂_xF_y-∂_yF_x=0$, we can conclude that $\oint F_xdx+F_ydy=0$ for any closed loop, from here I got stuck but I thought about finding some special loop where x and y are held constant at some line on the loop so after integrating we can get some function whose partial derivatives are the x,y component of F, but I couldn't get any further. If someone can give me some help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When $F$ has no singularities then those partial differential relations imply by Green's theorem that the integral (i.e. work done against force $F$) is zero for any closed loop. Is that not what we call conservative?

Comment: yes, but I mean how do we get from that to deducing F being a gradient of another scaler function?

Comment: You are trying to prove the [Poincare lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_lemma#Proof_in_the_two-dimensional_case). In your two dimensional case the link shows how to do it. It is pretty close to your own idea.

Comment: oh, thanks, I didn't know it's already a lemma

Comment: We are all standing on the shoulders of giants. You should also study the [famous case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605443/showing-why-a-form-is-not-exact/4605719#4605719) when that lemma does not hold.